# Convert System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo short date format to Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter

Tags: localization, datetime-format, uwp-xaml, globalization, cultureinfo

I am using a CalendarDatePicker control in UWP. The format of the date should be localized to the user's chosen culture, which is not necessarily the same as the OS language settings. I want the date format to appear the same as myCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern (e.g. mm/dd/yyyy). The CalendarDatePicker exposes a DateFormat property which is expected to be in a format like {month.integer}‎/‎{day.integer}‎/‎{year.full}. I need a converter for the XAML binding. It seems like there should be a simple way to do this.

```
<!-- In XAML -->
<CalendarDatePicker
    FirstDayOfWeek="{x:Bind ViewModel.CalendarFirstDayOfWeek, Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource SystemDayOfWeekToWindowsDayOfWeekConverter}}"
    DateFormat="{x:Bind ViewModel.DateFormat, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeFormatToDateTimeFormatterTemplateConverter}"
    Date="{x:Bind ViewModel.Date, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter}}"/>

//Converter
public class DateTimeFormatToDateTimeFormatterTemplateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //What goes here?
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Edit:
Ideally the CalendarDatePicker would just have a CultureInfo property that would take care of all of this. I tried the Language property but it had no noticeable effect.

Comment: You need to convert it by yourself. When you get the **ShortDatePattern** value, you can convert the CalendarDatePicker's DateTimeFormatter according to the value, such as the `ShortDatePattern="M/d/yyyy"` then you specify the `DateFormat="shortdate"`.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT can you please clarify with a code sample? The CalendarDatePicker's DateTimeFormatter is not publicly exposed, so I cannot set the ShortDatePattern on it. It looks like all I have access to is the DateFormat property, which is then passed to the DateTimeFormatter constructor.
I also tried something like this:               
Language="en-UK"
DateFormat="shortdate", but it did not work.

Comment: Correction: "en-UK" is not a valid language code. It works if I use a valid language code AND explicitly set the date format (e.g. "en-GB") AND bind the first day of the week. However, all of this still does not localize the names of the months in the calendar flyout.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you set the [CalendarDatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker)'s [DateTimeFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter) by use the [CalendarDatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker)'s [DateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.dateformat#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_CalendarDatePicker_DateFormat) Property which tells the [DateTimeFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter) how to format the value by providing a string that is either a format template or a format pattern. The [Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.language#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_Language) property is for getting or setting localization/globalization language information that applies to the [CalendarDatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker).

Different [Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.language#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_Language) with `shortdate` [DateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.dateformat#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_CalendarDatePicker_DateFormat) Property maybe also have differnt date format. You can just see the different with the language **en-US** and **fr-FR**.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <CalendarDatePicker Language="en-US" DateFormat="shortdate"/>
    <CalendarDatePicker Language="fr-FR" DateFormat="shortdate"/>
</StackPanel>
```

So you maybe need to use the [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2#the-current-culture-and-uwp-apps) Class to get the current culture.

For the [DateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.dateformat#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_CalendarDatePicker_DateFormat) convertion, you can get all the [ShortTimePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shorttimepattern?view=netstandard-2.0) from your device settings app: Settings=> Time & Language=> Data& time => Change date and time formats, in the **Short date** part, you can see all the format there. Then you can return corresponding [DateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.dateformat#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_CalendarDatePicker_DateFormat) string according to the [ShortTimePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shorttimepattern?view=netstandard-2.0). Here are some code sample:

```cs
var shortDataPattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
Debug.WriteLine(shortDataPattern);
        switch (shortDataPattern)
        {
            case "M/d/yyyy":
                // return "shortdate" or the following
                return "{}{month.integer}‎/‎{day.integer}‎/‎{year.full}";
            case "M/d/yy":
                return ...
            ...//Other format
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. I really want to avoid writing a switch statement for every possible date format. I discovered it will localize the date format if I set both the Language AND the DateFormat properties. I did not expect to have to explicitly set the DateFormat. 
However, now the issue is the month names are not localized when I set the Language property. Any suggestions there?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who ventures here, this will at least localize the date format and the first day of the week, but it does not localize the names of the months:

```
<CalendarDatePicker
    Language="{x:Bind ViewModel.CalendarLanguageCode, Mode=OneWay}"
    FirstDayOfWeek="{x:Bind ViewModel.CalendarFirstDayOfWeek, Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource SystemDayOfWeekToWindowsDayOfWeekConverter}}"
    DateFormat="shortdate"
    Date="{x:Bind ViewModel.Date, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

(The implementation of SystemDayOfWeekToWindowsDayOfWeekConverter is a trivial conversion from System.DayOfWeek to Windows.Globalization.DayOfWeek)